# How to check how many classes are loaded and how much space they will take?

Tags: java, java-8, jstat

I am planning to migrate to Java 8, before I want to check how many classes are being loaded in my project, and more important how much space they will take, so that I can tune and configure metaspace accordingly.

I know that I can use [jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html) for this purpose, but not sure what kind of parameters do I need to get the result I want.

Comment: Why do you assume that you'll need to tune the metaspace? It grows as needed by default.

Comment: Class metadata allocation  is limited by amount of available native memory, so I want to limit the amount of native memory based on the amount of classes I have.

Comment: But the JVM won't just keep allocating metadata of random classes; the only problem you may encounter is with an application which constantly creates new classes and disposes of old ones. This is not a normal scenario by any account.

Comment: Thanks for info, I will keep this into account.

Comment: For example, if you have JEE application container or Tomcat, and you often redeploy applications without restarting the JVM process, that may be a case where you need to control metaspace size.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some java profiler tool. Here are some of them [link](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/06/java-performance-tuning-tools/).
[YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/home/) is really decent but its not free.

Answer (score 1):

Use jconsole / jvisualvm from the bin of jdk. Its more intuitive and informative.

Comment: I dont even know that java have this tools. Splendid.